# arrow hover adding a circle div behind

Tags: html, css, hover

I have two arrow images (previous / next) with the code here like this:

```
.fp-controlArrow {
    position: absolute;
    width: 32px; /* This can be added here so you don't have to set a width and height 2 times for each arrow, this will create one width for both arrows */
    height: 32px; /* This does the same as above */
    margin-top:-15px; /* This value must always be half of the height - This does the same as above */
    z-index: 30;
    top: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.fp-controlArrow.fp-prev {
    left:0;
    background: url(https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/602dbecd2160ce28b5bc428b/602e923133f8dc0bf994fc49_left-arrow.svg) no-repeat;
}
.fp-controlArrow.fp-next {
    right:0;
    background: url(https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/602dbecd2160ce28b5bc428b/602e9231ec03b6c9682b540c_right-arrow.svg) no-repeat;
```

I would like when I hover over an arrow it a round transparent circle appeared behind the arrow like on this example:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpL2t.gif)

how can I achieve this?

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```css
padding: 1em;
border-radius: 50%;
background-color: rgba(200,200,200,0.5)
```

Add those lines to the `.fp-controlArrow` class That should do it.

### Edit

Sorry, I didn't realize it was svg. You will have to inline the svg.

```html
<div class="fp-controlArrow fp-prev">

  <svg width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" data-reactroot="">
    <path stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="1" stroke="#221b38" d="M16 20L8 12L16 4"></path>
  </svg>

</div>
<div class="fp-controlArrow fp-next">

  <svg width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" data-reactroot="">
    <path stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="1" stroke="#221b38" d="M8 20L16 12L8 4"></path>
  </svg>

</div>
```

```css
.fp-controlArrow {
    position: absolute;
    width: 32px; /* This can be added here so you don't have to set a width and height 2 times for each arrow, this will create one width for both arrows */
    height: 32px; /* This does the same as above */
    margin-top:-15px; /* This value must always be half of the height - This does the same as above */
    z-index: 30;
    top: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 1em;
    border-radius: 50%;

}

.fp-controlArrow:hover {
  background: green;
  background-color: rgba(200,200,200,0.5);
} 

.fp-controlArrow.fp-prev {
    left:0;
}
.fp-controlArrow.fp-next {
    right:0;
```

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/zachiah/pen/WNoOXyO?editors=1111) that demonstrates it.

Comment: Hi, have you tried this? I couldn't get it to work, I think because the images are SVGs, but maybe I did something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I didn't saw the space between : and hover.

```
.fp-controlArrow.fp-prev {
left:0;
background: url(https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/602dbecd2160ce28b5bc428b/602e923133f8dc0bf994fc49_left-arrow.svg) no-repeat;
border-radius: 50px;
}
.fp-controlArrow.fp-prev:hover{
background-color: #999999;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this works - the background images are svgs.

Comment: Apologies, I'd tried you code and it didn't work, but now I see there's a space between the : and the hover in your code which I hadn't noticed. If that is removed it's OK. Perhaps you could edit it out?

Comment: I actually tried your code and I don't find any problems with the svg file. Also you already put "no repeat" to the svg so there's no need to worry.